# How to make border not "thin" in PHPWord to prevent behaviours of "Enhance thin line" setting in Adobe Reader

Tags: php, ms-word, phpword, adobe-reader

First you have to understand the flow :

```
 PHPWord -> document.docx -> Microsoft Word -> document.pdf -> Adobe Reader
```

I create some tables in a .docx document with PHPWord :

```
private const CS_BORDER = 
[
    'borderSize' => 7, 
    'borderColor' => '000000',
];

$table = $section->addTable();
$row = $table->addRow();
$cell = $row->addCell(Font::centimeterSizeToTwips(5.3), self::CS_BORDER);
$cell->addText('Text', self::FS_CALIBRI_10_BOLD, self::PS_CENTER_ALIGN_NO_SPACE);
$cell = $row->addCell(Font::centimeterSizeToTwips(2.2), self::CS_BORDER);
$cell->addText('Text', self::FS_CALIBRI_10_BOLD, self::PS_CENTER_ALIGN_NO_SPACE);
$cell = $row->addCell(Font::centimeterSizeToTwips(2.4), self::CS_BORDER);
$cell->addText('Text', self::FS_CALIBRI_10_BOLD, self::PS_CENTER_ALIGN_NO_SPACE);
```

Then I manually export .docx to .pdf using Microsoft Word and opening it with Adobe Reader.

Like a lot of peoples I get render issues because of "Enhance thin line" setting in Adobe Reader.

**The point is :** lines are optimized even if I use following code   :

```
private const CS_BORDER = 
[
    'borderSize' => 50, 
    'borderColor' => '000000',
];
```

**My question is : Is there something to do in PHPWord to make Adobe Reader don't treats borders as thin line ?**

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the way to prevent Acrobat or Reader from its excessive bolding of rectangles is to insert additional anchor points on all straight lines of the shape. I do this in Adobe Illustrator, then export to EMF for use in Word. You'll have to investigate whether phpword can edit vectors at that level of detail.